# R language retrieve strings matched

Tags: regex, r

I need to retrieve string that contains "ARINA" word only. For instance there is a dataset `light` with the following columns:

```
CASEID
TIME_ELAPSED
```

Most of the string (`light$CASEID`) looks like:

```
CASEID 1 ARINA LIVES IN PARIS
CASEID 2 FRANCO LIVES IN SYDNEY
CASEID 3 ARINA WORKS FOR XXX COMPANY
CASEID 4 CARINA LIVES IN LIVERPOOL
```

etc

I tried to use the following expression to find only string where 'ARINA' exists:

```
light[grep("ARINA", light$CASEID),]
```

I would like to get `CASEID` 1 and 3 but in reality I get CASEID 1,3, and 4 (C**ARINA**)

Comment: `CASEID` 2 doesn't contain `ARINA` at all btw.

Comment: @DavidArenburg ahh, yes, i'm sorry for typo. I've updated description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries in-order to do an exact string match.

```
light[grep("\\bARINA\\b", light$CASEID),]
```

or if you need the actual value of `CASEID`, you can skip the subsetting step by specifying `value = TRUE` within `grep`

```
grep("\\bARINA\\b", light$CASEID, value = TRUE)
```

Comment: You could also do `grep("\\bARINA\\b", light$CASEID, value = TRUE)` in case they just need the actual value. Not sure what is the `perl = TRUE` option for

Comment: Think now it's ok. `light[grepl("\\bARINA\\b", light$CASEID),]`

Answer (score 0):

`light[grep("[^A-Za-z]ARINA[^A-Za-z]",light$CASEID)]` would work if you are only dealing with letters.